# Django staticfiles not being updated in browser

Tags: django, django-staticfiles

this is a weird error.  I'm working on a Django project in local.

when I make changes to staticfiles (.css and.js), they don't appear in the updated version in browsers.

So if I add new styles in a .css file, changes appear in Chrome but not in Firefox.

Similarly .js files changes appear in firefox but not in chrome.

First, I thought this a git branch issue, removed git, didn't work.

I also tried cleaning browser cache and force refresh the website.

What's wrong?

Comment: Have you used `collectstatic` at all? Is this at dev pc? Any relevant django cache middleware that may affect it possibly? If you restart the server does it fix? What does the browser dev tools network activity tell you?

Comment: am not using any cache middleware..I tried restarting the server, also the system. Didn't work..when I open those files in browser, they are the old files, changes do not appear.
But if I make another copy of that file..with a new name..changes appear!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get the same error sometimes when developing on local. The best solution I came up is restarting the browser. I still don`t know if is a Chrome related issue as it happens also with other frameworks(on local development). Try to clear your browser cache.

Comment: nothing works :D ..only this:  if I make another copy of that file..with a new name..changes appear!

Comment: Might be a text editor issue. Try to close and save the files before checking them on the dev server. Also in Chrome go to view page source and see the css files that get loaded. You should not have to use collectstatic in dev mode in Django by the way. Updates of static files should be automatic.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming "local mode" means you are running a regular `runserver`, check out if you are not running two copies of it!  (In windows, open your task manager and check for more, unwanted instances of `python.exe` and kill them).

If you are not using `runserver`, but a production server, consider using a [cache busting](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#manifeststaticfilesstorage) technique.

Comment: am using runserver in local on Ubuntu and there's just one copy of it. I don't know about cache busting technique.